# Why does vmlinux get SIGKILL when I try to run it?

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, sigkill

I have unpacked my `vmlinuz` into a `vmlinux` and tried to execute it, just to see what would happen. However, the binary gets SIGKILL on startup!

Why does this happen?

I was expecting a SIGILL (kernel tries to do something that is not allowed in user space) or a SIGSEGV (trying to access kernel memory not allowed in user-mode not allowed to access), but not a SIGKILL!

Is the process sending SIGKILL to itself, or is it being killed? GDB doesn't help -- the message is `During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.`

The max resident memory is only 412kB per `/bin/time` so the OOM killer is not the culprit. In fact, the SIGKILL is sent even if I have the OOM killer disabled by `echo 2 | sudo dd of=/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`.

Comment: It would appear that whatever happens is happening before execution ever reaches the entry point address - ie, none of code is executed.  An obvious guess would be that the elf sections specified for loading into kernel reserved regions are not permitted to user mode programs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are correct -- I think it is trying to load into a forbidden address.